# How to merge certain datarows in a dataset with multiple unique values vb

Tags: vb.net, select, time, merge, dataset

The title might be difficult to understand so here's a short explanation :
I have to create a method :

MergeDataset(byval ds as Dataset) as dataset

- The datatable has multiple rows
- The columns : startDate, endDate, and multiple others

**The dataset is ordered by startDate**

What I do now :

- I create a clone of the dataset, which is empty ofcourse
- I loop through every datarow in the datatable

  **If** the datarow has a value in the clone dataset which equals all columns(except startdate and endate)
  and the enddate of the clone equals the startdate of the datarow - 1 day

**else** the row is added to the clone

This now is done correctly, but takes a lot of time.
When I have a dataset of 100 000 rows, it takes multiple houres to merge them all.

Here some code :

```
Dim mergeSet As DataSet = dsSubscriptions.Clone()
Dim dr() As DataRow = ds.Tables("resultTable").Select("","startDate")
For Each sourceRow As DataRow In dr

If mergeSet.Tables("resultTable").Rows.Count > 0 Then
     Dim foundRows As DataRow() = mergeSet.Tables("resultTable").Select(endDate=startDate-1 and value1 = value1 and value2 = value2 and value3 = value3)    
'If nothing in foundRows -> Add row
For Each resultrow As DataRow In foundRows
resultrow("endDate") = CDate(sourceRow("endDate"))
next
else
'Add row
Next
```

A lot of time gets lost in the select of the mergeSet, if I check timespans they're increasing a lot. The select has 5 unique values, and rows can be merged if all values equal eachother, and the dates can be merged into one period.

Small example :

id  startDate   endDate      value1   value2    value3

1   1-11-2012   30-11-2012  A   B   C   Add to Merge

2   1-12-2012   31-12-2012  A   B   C   Merge with 1

3   1-1-2013    31-1-2013   A   B   B   Add to Merge(not same values as 2)

Any help is welcome!
Kind regards

Comment: Can you improve the time with something like http://pastebin.com/1G7vaHRh?

Comment: Add an index on the field that has [highest cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(SQL_statements)).